# Upload Images to Firebase Storage and have a link in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am currently working on an Incident Reporting application which allows users to choose and upload images.

I am already successful in posting images to Firebase Storage but I am wondering if it is possible to have a link/url in Firebase Database from which I can click to redirect me to Firebase Storage to see that image.

I want this function so that along with user inputs such as Title, Date, Remarks, the end-user would be able to see the "image" child with the link along with other inputs

I have tried searching StackOverflow and Youtube for answers but most of them are old and seem outdated. There is a command "getDownloadUrl" but i believe it has been deprecated.

This is the code from my class that uploads my image to Firebase Storage

```
  private void uploadImage() {

    if (filePath != null) {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Failed"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded"+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }
}

private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

ReportFragment

```
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI.getApplicationContext;

public class ReportFragment extends Fragment implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Button btnChoose,btnUpload;
private ImageView imageView;
private Uri filePath;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
private TextView mDisplayDate;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

private EditText reportedBy;
private TextView date; //upstairs declare alr as mDisplayDate
private Spinner spinner; //downstairs declare alr as spinner3
private EditText location;
private Spinner spinner2; //downstairs declare alr as spinner2
private EditText details;
private Spinner spinner3; //downstairs declare alr as spinner1
private EditText remarks;
private EditText title;
private Button submitIncident;


public static TextView resultTextView3;
Button scan_btn3;

private ImageView imageView2;
private TextView imgUrl1;

DatabaseReference databaseIncidents;
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false);

    databaseIncidents = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Incidents");
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();

    btnChoose = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    btnUpload = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    reportedBy = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etreportedby);
//        Below have already line 151
//        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
    location = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etlocation);
    details = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etdetails);
    remarks = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etremarks);
    title = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ettitle);
    submitIncident = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);


    resultTextView3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.result_text3);
    scan_btn3 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_scan3);

    imageView2 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivimagescardinput);
    imgUrl1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvimagescard);






    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseImage();
        }
    });
//        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                uploadImage();
//            }
//        });


    scan_btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new 
Intent(getActivity(),ScanCodeActivity.class));

        }
    });

    submitIncident.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            incidentSubmit();
            uploadImage();

            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(URL).into(imageView2);
        }
    });

    return`


}

private void incidentSubmit(){
    String reportedname = reportedBy.getText().toString().trim();
    String location1 = location.getText().toString();
    String details1 = details.getText().toString();
    String remarks1 = remarks.getText().toString();
    String urgency1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String type1 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String splocation1 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String date1 = mDisplayDate.getText().toString();
    String title1 = title.getText().toString();
    String qrlocation1 = resultTextView3.getText().toString();
    String image1 = imgUrl1.getText().toString();


    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(reportedname)) {

        String incidentId = databaseIncidents.push().getKey();
        Incident incident = new 



Incident(reportedname,location1,details1,remarks1,urgency1,type1,splocation1,date1,title1,qrlocation1,image1);
            databaseIncidents.child(incidentId).setValue(incident);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Incident Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new IncmanFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "All fields must be entered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
private void uploadImage() {


    if (filePath != null) {

        final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());

       ref.putFile(filePath).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
               if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                   ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                           String URL = uri.toString();
                           databaseIncidents.child("imageId").setValue(URL.toString());

                       }

                   });

               }

           }

       });

    }


}


private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Any help or tutorials is greatly appreciated!

[Database Inputs (not including image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WafEh.png)

Answer (score 0):

For storing the images to your Firebase Storage, you first set a correct reference and just store the image there, very similar to Firebase Database data storing.

To have a link in the Firebase Database, you can just use `downloadUri` you can get from storage and have it stored in the database.

The code for this looks something like this, you can take an inspiration from this and come up with a code that suits you more:

```java
private void uploadFile(Bitmap bitmap) {

        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

        final StorageReference ImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/"+mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid()+".jpg");


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        final UploadTask uploadTask = ImagesRef.putBytes(data);



        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.i("whatTheFuck:",exception.toString());
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.

                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i("problem", task.getException().toString());
                        }

                        return ImagesRef.getDownloadUrl(); 
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(mAu.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                            Log.i("seeThisUri", downloadUri.toString());// This is the one you should store

                            ref.child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUri.toString());


                        } else {
                            Log.i("wentWrong","downloadUri failure");
                        }
                    }
                });
             }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hi, do I need to include that ByteArrayOutputStream codes? I don't really understand

Comment: That part of the code is to compress the image, so you don't take up much space in the Firebase storage, also it converts the image to bytes array.

Comment: When I add that part, my button for onClickListener has an error, probably because I declared "Bitmap bitmap" in the private void uploadFile()

Comment: Can you show the error statement, if you're not able to get the error solved.

Comment: Hi, I kind of solved the error. Now there are no errors but it is not working. I'm not sure if I have edited it right. There are other parts that are linked to the application so I am not sure if I have to add more things for this image. I will show you my firebase database

Comment: @stanloona you can see in the log with tag "seeThisUri" and compare it with the url you have in your Firebase Storage. If they are same, (which they should be) then probably it should work, or something else is going wrong, I can look into that, can you first confirm what I just told you :)

Comment: When you say the url in my Firebase Storage, do you mean my folder url? Moreover, should that command  "Log.i("seeThisUri", downloadUri.toString());" actually be touched or left alone? Sorry if I sound dumb, first time doing this part.

Comment: Just see in your logcat, and search by `seeThisUri`, after running the code in emulator or demo device. You will see a url in it, compare it to the one you see in your Firebase Storage for the same image that you uploaded. This should be same.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you can upload images to storage succesfully but you are having trouble when you want to get that image direct url.

Try this code:

```
StorageReference storageRef=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    storageRef.putFile(filePath).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String URL = uri.toString();
                        //This is your image url do whatever you want with it.
                    }
                });
            }     
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I'll try this and let you know!

Comment: Hi, I can see it in my Firebase Storage. Do I have to create a new output as shown in the picture? For example, maybe a new child titled "image". Then will the URL be shown in the Firebase Database?

Comment: Thats your image url.Its up to you what to do next.If you want to get that image later you should save that url to firebase databse.Also you can get image url with stırage reference but since you are using random id to save them its easier to save url to database.

Comment: Should the name of the image be an actual url or just randomly generated id? Because right now the name just looks like my other random id generated images. Thanks.

Comment: You can't name image actual URL because you can't get URL before upload.So random generated id is fine.

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider to accept it as best answer.Thanks

Comment: Hi sorry, then can I ask, so to create my output for the URL the data type would be under String right?

Comment: And is it possible to link the String url to imageView? For my application when the user open ups a CardView of a sample incident, I would like the application if it could display the image, not the URL. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: yes in my example its string.İf you want to load image from url i suggest you to use Glide.     https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Okay, I shall try glide first and see how it goes!

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to use glide but it does not take recognize the URL in the "String URL = uri.toString()" in the uploadImage() method. I have tried creating a method just for this to no avail. I also tried putting it in my onClickListener of my submitIncident button but can't as well. Any suggestions? The command I tried is "Glide.with(getActivity()).load(URL).into(imageView2)". My app just keep crashing now.

Comment: Have posted, please check